# Как конвертировать JSON/XML в CSV/XLS?

Tags: python, json, xml, csv

Есть файл JSON (попутно конвертировал в XML) размером 60МБ, где каждая строка имеет по два значения:

```
{"item1": "default", "item2":"1473"}
```

или же то же самое в XML:

```
<root><item1>Название</item1><item2>1473</Way></root>
```

Как можно с помощью Python правильно конвертировать их в CSV/XLS?

P.S. В `item1` часто попадаются запятые.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример входного JSON:

```
[
 {"item1": "default", "item2":"1473"},
 {"item1": "a,b,c", "item2":"4567"}
]
```

Конвертация `JSON` --> `CSV`:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

pd.read_json(r"C:\temp\test.json").to_csv(r"c:\temp\result.csv", index=False)
```

Результат:

```
item1,item2
default,1473
"a,b,c",4567
```

---

Конвертация `JSON` --> `Excel`:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

pd.read_json(r"C:\temp\test.json").to_excel(r"c:\temp\result.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что надо =)